# SQL loader latin characters are wrongly communicated to target database

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

When i try a control file that has a table name as "MySchema"."X_ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇ", like below:

```
OPTIONS(silent=feedback,rows=5000,errors=2000,READSIZE=9999999,BINDSIZE=9999999,Direct=False)
LOAD DATA
**CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252**
APPEND INTO TABLE "ABC"."X_ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇ"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "  " 
...
(we specify the input file using command line arguments)
```

While running, am getting an error like below:

```
SQL*Loader-941: Error during describe of table "ABC"."X_ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇ"
ORA-04043: object "ABC"."X_????????" does not exist
```

I have specified the CHARACTERSET, as well as set my NLS_LANG parameter both as environment variable and in registry of client.

sqlldr output:

```
SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Thu May 29 07:19:06 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Control File:   X_ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇ.CTL
Character Set WE8MSWIN1252 specified for all input.

Data File:      X_ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇ.EXT
  Bad File:     X_ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇ.bad
  Discard File:  none specified

 (Allow all discards)

Number to load: ALL
Number to skip: 0
Errors allowed: 0
Bind array:     5000 rows, maximum of 9999999 bytes
Continuation:    none specified
Path used:      Conventional
Silent options: FEEDBACK
Table "ABC"."X_ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇ", loaded from every logical record.
Insert option in effect for this table: APPEND
TRAILING NULLCOLS option in effect

   Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
A_ID                           FIRST         *  WHT      CHARACTER            
C_ID                           NEXT          *  WHT      CHARACTER            
D_ID                           NEXT          *  WHT      CHARACTER            
G_C                            NEXT          *  WHT      CHARACTER            
ÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓ                       NEXT          *  WHT      CHARACTER            
PLACED_DATE                    NEXT          *  WHT      CHARACTER            


SQL*Loader-941: Error during describe of table "ABC"."X_ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇ"
ORA-04043: object "ABC"."X_????????" does not exist
```

Any help?

Comment: Maybe finally shift to UTF8 which should save all non-ANSI characters?

Comment: I tried with UTF8, it did not help. Character set WE8MSWIN1252 also supports all those characters in my table name. Is there any other place that i should specify my character set other than in control file and NLS_LANG key/parameter?

Comment: Naming database objects like tables and columns with non-ASCII symbols isn't a good thing. Looks like character set conversion error in one of internal `sqlldr` queries used to describe table. First thing to do is to double-check `NLS_LANG` settings in environment variable.

Comment: Another thing is to check if "MySchema" user from the start of the question have all required privileges on table `"ABC"."X_ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇ"`

Comment: @ThinkJet, I see that NLS_LANG is present in registry with a correct value. I believe if we create an environment variable for NLS_LANG, then it will be common for all Oracle client homes. Do we require to create NLS_LANG environment variable, when it is already present in registry?

Comment: Setting of `NLS_LANG` in environment variable is needed just to be sure that in concrete run `sqlldr` used proper value of this setting. Open command window (cmd.exe), execute `SET NLS_LANG=...` and run `sqlldr` in this window aftewards. If problem disappear then it's about reading `NLS_LANG`, if not - you need to search for solution in other direction.

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Not sure why it was not able to read the parameter earlier. But i was able to make progress now.  Thanks..